# How do I modify a lot of bones without Blender becoming slow?

Tags: animation, scripting

I am making a script that pulls pose data from a few different programs that I have made. My question is what could be the best way to apply this without making Blender very slow. At the moment I just loop through all bones that needs to be changed and update them like this:

```
for b in input_data.bones:
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[b.name].rotation_euler = (b.x, b.y, b.z)

for s in input_data.shapekeys:
    bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.004'].key_blocks[s.name].value = s.value
```

This worked in the beginning but the more stuff I add to be modified the slower Blender becomes. Sometimes it just crash.

I don't really know how Blender handles the changes but I believe that the Viewport updates each time something is changed? I may be wrong.

First I thought if there is a way to pause the Viewport from updating, and let it update once all changes are made to the pose.

Another thing was to try add keyframes to the next frame instead of changing the current frame. Thus when you press play it should only update everything once with the values of the keyframes. My issue here is that I can not figure out how to insert a keyframe without changing the value of the current frame.

This I have not tried but if you can make a copy of the current pose, modify the copy and then replace the current with the copy. I have not looked into pose library yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that it is a limitation of Python. C++ code is extremely fast in comparison with Python. Can you elaborate more in numerals? What is the number of bones and FPS?

Comment: There are currently 35 bones that I want to modify each frame. Right now it is not really updating on a frame by frame basis, but rather "update bones -> sleep(time) -> repeat". I would rather bind it to the framerate instead. Is there a "run this funcion on next frame" function in the API maybe?